# Don't separate section heading from its line

Tags: titlesec

I have my sections format defined with titlesec like this:

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{HTML}{A3B9FF}


\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{20pt}{\bf  \Huge}
\titleformat{\section}{}{}{1pt}{\bfseries \Large}[\color{shadecolor}\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{40pt}{10pt}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis malesuada arcu nec bibendum pellentesque. Vivamus id volutpat tellus, vitae volutpat dolor. Etiam ultrices a mauris a mattis. Curabitur sed lacus sit amet tortor blandit tempus quis sed nibh. Donec ipsum libero, ornare sit amet sodales vitae, hendrerit eget justo. Cras varius sed nibh in tincidunt. Suspendisse facilisis imperdiet diam eu accumsan. In mollis sollicitudin mauris adipiscing interdum. Etiam quis porta nunc. Fusce accumsan mauris at iaculis semper. Sed in ligula nec dolor condimentum euismod.

In sodales, nisi id tincidunt accumsan, enim enim varius velit, id pulvinar massa sem id augue. Proin facilisis neque in sapien fermentum, sit amet bibendum ipsum gravida. Suspendisse et blandit erat. Fusce lacinia pulvinar mauris eu molestie. Duis laoreet risus ut viverra dignissim. Nulla ultricies, nulla vel placerat tempor, purus est lobortis lectus, malesuada posuere sem mauris nec ante. Nulla rutrum orci quis lacus tristique blandit. Suspendisse mattis mi lorem, at condimentum eros ultrices sed.

Phasellus condimentum egestas suscipit. Sed a blandit enim, et adipiscing felis. Ut in euismod nisl. Quisque feugiat auctor leo volutpat tincidunt. Donec vitae metus nibh. Donec aliquet metus sem, at lacinia risus tincidunt eu. Nulla porttitor varius mi eget vehicula. Phasellus euismod tortor arcu, in varius eros ultricies eu. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin facilisis nulla vel dui pretium congue. Fusce a dignissim diam, nec mollis sem. Quisque in sollicitudin augue, non dignissim erat. Donec elementum porttitor purus vel semper. Mauris nisl ligula, ultrices non tellus at, ornare lacinia mi. Integer et ullamcorper lorem.

Aenean aliquam vulputate eros eget porttitor. Nullam posuere luctus neque, porta commodo mi suscipit ac. In sit amet sollicitudin libero. Nulla nec viverra nulla, ut pulvinar nisi. Curabitur sed orci eget lorem condimentum pulvinar.

\section{Second section}

More Text. More text.
\end{document}
```

The "problem" here is that sometimes the heading gets separated from its rule by a page break. Is there some way to treat the whole heading as a unit so it doesn't get separated?

Comment: As an aside, please consider reading [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: No, `\textbf` takes an argument, which in your case will be `\Large` and is therefore incorrect. You were probably thinking about using `\bfseries`. Now my second suggestion would be to provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than a code snippet; something that replicates your problem. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok. New at this. Added MWE!

Comment: Does `\titleformat{\section}{}{}{1pt}{\bfseries \Large}[\titleline{\color{shadecolor}\titlerule}]` work good enough for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose your title rule in the `\titleline{}`-command. This binds the rule to your section title.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{HTML}{A3B9FF}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{20pt}{\bfseries \Huge}
\titleformat{\section}{}{}{1pt}{\bfseries \Large}[\titleline{\color{shadecolor}\titlerule}]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{40pt}{10pt}
\usepackage[final]{microtype} % not needed, but looks so much nicer...

\begin{document}    
    \chapter{First Chapter} 
    \section{First section} 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis malesuada arcu nec bibendum pellentesque. Vivamus id volutpat tellus, vitae volutpat dolor. Etiam ultrices a mauris a mattis. Curabitur sed lacus sit amet tortor blandit tempus quis sed nibh. Donec ipsum libero, ornare sit amet sodales vitae, hendrerit eget justo. Cras varius sed nibh in tincidunt. Suspendisse facilisis imperdiet diam eu accumsan. In mollis sollicitudin mauris adipiscing interdum. Etiam quis porta nunc. Fusce accumsan mauris at iaculis semper. Sed in ligula nec dolor condimentum euismod.

    In sodales, nisi id tincidunt accumsan, enim enim varius velit, id pulvinar massa sem id augue. Proin facilisis neque in sapien fermentum, sit amet bibendum ipsum gravida. Suspendisse et blandit erat. Fusce lacinia pulvinar mauris eu molestie. Duis laoreet risus ut viverra dignissim. Nulla ultricies, nulla vel placerat tempor, purus est lobortis lectus, malesuada posuere sem mauris nec ante. Nulla rutrum orci quis lacus tristique blandit. Suspendisse mattis mi lorem, at condimentum eros ultrices sed.

    Phasellus condimentum egestas suscipit. Sed a blandit enim, et adipiscing felis. Ut in euismod nisl. Quisque feugiat auctor leo volutpat tincidunt. Donec vitae metus nibh. Donec aliquet metus sem, at lacinia risus tincidunt eu. Nulla porttitor varius mi eget vehicula. Phasellus euismod tortor arcu, in varius eros ultricies eu. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin facilisis nulla vel dui pretium congue. Fusce a dignissim diam, nec mollis sem. Quisque in sollicitudin augue, non dignissim erat. Donec elementum porttitor purus vel semper. Mauris nisl ligula, ultrices non tellus at, ornare lacinia mi. Integer et ullamcorper lorem.

    Aenean aliquam vulputate eros eget porttitor. Nullam posuere luctus neque, porta commodo mi suscipit ac. In sit amet sollicitudin libero. Nulla nec viverra nulla, ut pulvinar nisi. Curabitur sed orci eget lorem condimentum pulvinar.    
    \section{Second section}    
    More Text. More text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly!